# glm::perspective isn't working?

Tags: camera, perspective, glm, glfw

So I'm learning how to make games and program, and while trying to setup a projection camera using GLM in GFLW, this line of code refuses to work and I can't figuire out why. The code is in the image below.
                                                 Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Side note: Posting the code as text in the future would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the width and height of the window were actually ints they needed to be floats so I just casted it to a float and it worked.

Comment: See the updated answer; straight casting to float as in your comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The message you're seeing is saying your argument types aren't right. As 3 of the arguments are `float` values and they correctly match, then that means `m_windowWidth / m_windowHeight` must be an integer when it needs to be a float. So, try:

```
glm::perspective(45.0f, m_windowWidth / static_cast<float>(m_windowHeight), 0.1f, 100f);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it made me realize how dumb I was, but actually the window width and height were actually ints and they needs to be floats so i did, glm::perspective(45.0f, (float) (m_windowWidth / m_windowHeight), 0.1f, 100f); and it worked

Comment: @Alalayo Ah I slightly misread your IDE - edited.

Comment: @user94189 thanks for the edit; it's the middle of the night here so I straight copied the above comment without considering that it's doing an integer division - I think it's time to go and get some sleep! :P

Comment: @Alalayo that is not going to be 100% correct. `m_windowWidth / m_windowHeight` is an int expression which will be calculated as int (truncating the numbers after the decimal) and only after the truncation will the number be converted to floating point. Instead convert one or both of the variables to float.